# Open Graph traversal

Tags: database, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

Any ideas how to solve a query problem like “give me names of all the `foo:Group` objects that my friends have a `foo:Join` action on”? (`foo:Group` and `foo:Join` are an open graph object and an action, respectively.)

Might it be possible to do some simple traversal like `GET fb./me/friends/foo:Join/groups?fields=name`?

I was also noticing that FQL wouldn't recognize open graph actions, so right now I'm not coming up with any other option than to query each friend separately — or in batches of 20 — which makes the job practically unfeasible.

Comment: I would love to see an FQL or Graph API solution in addition to the "build your own" answer which applies to nearly every question on SO. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the actions on your end whenever the user joins a group and then do the join yourself.

Alternatively, you can get `/me/friends` and then query every friend's `/<id>/foo:Join/groups`. You can use the batch API to help speed this up.